# Expected angle between bivariate normal vectors

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, correlation

I am trying to find an expression for the expected angle between two correlated gaussian vectors, i.e., find $E[\theta] = E\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\bf x_1'x_2}{\|\bf x_1\|\|x_2\|}\right)\right]$ where $\bf x_1$ and $\bf x_2$ $\in R^2$,
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\bf x_1\\
\bf x_2\end{array}\right) \sim N(\bf 0,\Sigma)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\bf \Sigma = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\bf \Sigma_{11} &\bf \Sigma_{12}\\
\bf \Sigma_{21} &\bf \Sigma_{22} \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
and $\bf \Sigma_{12}=\bf \Sigma_{21}' \neq \bf 0$. Assume all covariance submatrices are known. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is... zero, if your angles' range is $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie, this isn't true.

Comment: @zhoraster I meant working with oriented angles as you see my interval, without reference to $arccos$ which is "dangerous" to use when coping with angles. If it is the absolute value of angles, it's a different thing...

Comment: @JeanMarie, you should understand that oriented angles beyond dimension 2 are nonsense. Concerning the question itself, it is hopeless,  and I see no motivation to ask a question like that.

Comment: @JeanMarie : That is certainly not true. Suppose, for example, that $$ \bf\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.99 \\  0.99 & 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$ The expected value of the cosine then is close to $1. \qquad$

Comment: @ zhoraster I am sorry, but you should not use "nonsense" : the OP says explicitly he/she works in 2D.

Comment: @JeanMarie : If it's in two dimensions, then even with zero correlation between the two, you could have $$ \bf \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.99 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.99 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0.99 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.99 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$ and the probability that both are close to the line $y=x$ is high, so the expected cosine is near $1. \qquad$

Comment: @JeanMarie, I'm sorry,  I was misguided by the notation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes for the expected cosine, but what can be said about the expected angle ?

Comment: Let me add: I know $E[cos(\theta)]$ is the expected value of the dot product of two correlated angular central Gaussian distributions (defined as $\bf x/||\bf x||$ for $\bf x \sim N(\bf 0,\Sigma)$, see Mardia and Jupp, Directional Statistics, p. 46). While I am interested in the distribution of the angle, the distribution of the cosine is good enough for the application I have, which has a story too long to tell here. Thanks so much to Michael et al.

Comment: @JeanMarie : What can be said about the expected angle in that case is that it's near $0.\qquad$

Comment: Following my previous comment: $E[cos(\theta)]$, given that it is the dot product of two correlated angular central Gaussians, it will have an expectation given by the trace of their cross-covariance matrix, $tr(\bf \Sigma_{12})$, from Corollary 2.2 in Mathai, ``On bilinear froms in correlated normals", Ann. Inst. Math. Stat., 44, 4, pp. 769-799, 1992. (see my comment to [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2289788/448209).

Comment: Where I am confused, however, is how the normalization of each vector $\bf x_1$ and $\bf x_2$, when divided by their respective norms, affects the cross-covariance, because I know I can get $E[cos(\theta)$ from its trace. My intuition is that these are transformed into correlations due to the normalization. Regarding @MichelHardy's example, couldn't you also get the cosine near -1 if the cross-correlations were highly negative?